# Coroutines: main() runBlocking vs suspend main

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Take the following two samples of code (taken from the Kotlin documentation and from the Coroutines library README respectively):

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("World")
    }
    println("Hello")
}
```

In Kotlin >= 1.3.0 one can mark the `main()` function as `suspend`able and use a `coroutineScope` directly.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("World")
    }
    println("Hello")
}
```

Both produce the same output:

```
Hello
World
```

Are there any functional differences between the two approaches? If yes, what are they?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`runBlocking()` and `coroutineScope()` are functionally very similar. They both pause the current execution waiting until the inner coroutine finishes. The difference is that `runBlocking()` is meant to be executed from a regular non-suspendable code, so it waits by blocking and `coroutineScope()` is used from suspendable context, so it suspends.

That difference makes them do much different things internally. `runBlocking()` has to first initialize the whole coroutines machinery before it could execute a suspendable lambda. `coroutineScope()` has access to existing coroutine context, so it only schedules the inner lambda to be executed and suspends.

Now, `suspend fun main()` is just a "shortcut" that Kotlin compiler provides to make it easier to initialize coroutines apps. Internally, it creates a bridge between the real main function and your suspendable main function. It generates a separate `main()` function, which is not suspendable and is the "real" main function. This function initializes a coroutine and uses internal `runSuspend()` utility to execute your `suspend fun main()`. This is described here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/enhancing-main-convention.md#implementation-details-on-jvm-1

Both methods of starting a coroutine application are very similar and you can choose according to your taste. One notable difference is that `runBlocking()` creates a dispatcher using the current "main" thread. `suspend fun main()` also executes using the main thread, but it doesn't specify the dispatcher, so whenever you use e.g. `coroutineScope()` it will switch to `Dispatchers.Default`. As a result, your `runBlocking()` example uses single-threaded dispatcher while your `coroutineScope()` example uses multi-threaded `Dispatchers.Default`. However, this difference should not really be taken into account when choosing between both methods. We can very easily switch dispatchers at any time.